# Cannot delete morphpivot Custom model laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, polymorphic-associations

I am using laravel for a project and am having some issue deleting custom morphPivot relations.

When i try deleting a relation, I get the following error:

```
Illuminate/Database/QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '' in 'where clause' (SQL: delete from `comment` where (`` = 01418755-c68e-4ea5-8043-cef348c47445))'
```

From it I figure that laravel is trying to delete by the ids but the id column has no name so it cannot find it. However, I think I clearly defined the id column. Here are my class implementation:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use App\Traits\CanBeBlocked;
use App\Traits\CanBeGhosted;
use App\Traits\CanBeVoted;
use App\Traits\HasUuid;
use GraphQL\Type\Definition\ResolveInfo;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\MorphPivot;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Nuwave\Lighthouse\Support\Contracts\GraphQLContext;

class Comment extends MorphPivot
{
    use HasUuid,
        CanBeBlocked,
        CanBeGhosted,
        CanBeVoted;

    protected $casts = [
        'id' => 'string'
    ];

    protected $fillable = [
        'id',
        'parent_id',
        'user_id',
        'commentable_id',
        'commentable_type',
        'content',
        'created_at',
        'updated_at'
    ];

    public $incrementing = false;
    public $keyType = 'string';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    /**
     * @brief Users commenting another model
     */
    public function commenter()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'user_id');
    }

    /**
     * @brief models commented by a User
     */
    public function commentable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }

    /**
     * @brief replies of the comment
     */
    public function replies()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Comment', 'parent_id');
    }

    public function parent()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Comment');
    }

    public function repliers()
    {
        return $this->replies->map(function ($reply, $key) {
            return $reply->commenter;
        });
    }

    public function isReply()
    {
        return $this->parent_id !== null;
    }

    public function commentOnly($root, array $args, GraphQLContext $context, ResolveInfo $resolveInfo): Builder
    {
        return Comment::where('parent_id', null);
    }
}
```

and migrations:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateCommentTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('comment', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->uuid('id');
            $table->primary('id');
            $table->text('content');
            $table->boolean('spoiler')->default(false);
            $table->boolean('hidden')->default(false);
            $table->boolean('edited')->default(false);
            $table->uuid('parent_id')->nullable();
            $table->uuid('user_id');
            $table->uuid('commentable_id');
            $table->string('commentable_type');
            $table->json('meta')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('comment');
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Laravel v6.18.26

Comment: Can you share the code where you're trying to delete?

Comment: I use tinker to try and delete like App\Comment::first() - >delete(). It works for the other models.

Comment: Try this `dd(Comment::first()) ;` and paste the output here.

Comment: Here it is in tinker

App\Comment {#3667
     id: "01418755-c68e-4ea5-8043-cef348c47445",
     content: "Super frangins",
     spoiler: 0,
     hidden: 0,
     edited: 0,
     parent_id: null,
     user_id: "5311700e-6271-442d-84b6-f810d902001f",
     commentable_id: "d299b3d2-7996-46eb-a3e9-bd2883647aff",
     commentable_type: "App\Amadiora",
     meta: null,
     created_at: "2019-03-21 06:43:22",
     updated_at: "2019-03-21 06:43:22",
   }

ps: sorry, I don't know how to format code in comments

Comment: I changed the model to extend Pivot instead of MorphPivot and it can be deleted without problem I think MorphPivot delete method might be the problem here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed now in Laravel latest versions